# Query MySql comparando com array PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Preciso montar uma query em SQL para pesquisar mais de um valor.

Tipo:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE id = 10 OR id = 20 .....
```

Porém achei essa opção:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE id IN (' . implode(',', array_map('intval', $idgrupos)) . ')
```

Ele funciona, mas o problema é que o id tem que ser igual a todos os idgrupos passados no array. Eu queria que retornasse se achasse pelo menos um igual no array. Como faço?

Comment: "tem que ser igual a todos"? Como assim? A cláusula `in` verifica se o valor está contido em uma lista.

Comment: A cláusula IN como o nome diz verifica se o id está dentro dos elementos citados dentro do parêntese: ou seja
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5):
se um dos id estiver entre 1 a 5, ele irá retornar quantos achar,
logo em minha tabela tem os ids 2 , 3 , 6 , 
o SELECT citado irá retornar as linha com os ids 2 e 3 pois eles estão "IN" neste conjunto possível (1,2,3,4,5)